# Does an observable make a get request?

Tags: javascript, angular, http-get

When we use observables in angular2 and let's say we make a get request which returns a observable.

Does it this observable automatically issue a get request or does the subscribe issue a get request when we call it

Example:

Is the server called here? `this.http.get(requestUrl).map(this.validateResponse).map(this.parseJson);`

or here (after subscribe)

```
this.http.get(requestUrl).map(this.validateResponse).map(this.parseJson).subscribe(result=> console.log(result));
```

Comment: It's the subscription that starts the call. And it is "logical", if there is no subscription attached to an observable, it's useless to start the call or firing events (in the case of events).

Comment: Did you try it? What happened? `@angular/http` or `@angular/common/http`? Did you read [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/http), which tell you?

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ Tnx, you can make an answer for points

Comment: @masterach Done ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Observable` is only a type/wrapper around a data (async call, event, ...) which we want to observe (getting a data, react to an event,...).

So, if you don't `subscribe` to `changes` on it, there's nothing happening.

You have to make subscriptions to get data when using `http.get`.

You can take a look to these article to ahve a good overview of Observables: https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/observables/using_observables.html

Answer (score 1):

Observable is cold by default (no subscribe - no request performed).
Use .share() operator to make the Observable hot.
It's described here: https://auth0.com/blog/making-use-of-rxjs-angular/